# Create directory based on date/time and copy files to it?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, debian

I'm attempting to create a script that will create a folder based on the current time and date. I then need the script to copy the files from a source folder to the newly created folder. I then need it to copy folders from a second source folder to the original source folder, overwriting everything that's in there.

Below is what I've tried, and it's failing in quite an epic fashion.

```
#!/bin/bash

d="/home/$(date +%d-%m-%y")"
mkdir "$d"
cp /home/test "$d"
cp /home/test2 /home/test
```

I'm aware that I don't have to define the variable, as the time between copies should be seconds and not lapse a day, but I wanted to make sure and honestly, I'm interested in learning to use variables in scripting.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You say you need to _"copy the files from a source folder"_ but `cp /home/test somewhere` will only work if `/home/test` is a _file_. You could `cp /home/test/* /some/dir/` or `cp -r /home/test /some/dir/`

Comment: *"... and it's failing in quite an epic fashion."* - the problem statement is not very helpful. Please detail how it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one too many double quote here:

> ```
> d="/home/$(date +%d-%m-%y")"
> ```

Actually no quoting is necessary here at all, write like this:

```
d=/home/$(date +%d-%m-%y)
```

In the rest of the script, if you want to copy directories, you will need to use `cp -r` instead of simply `cp`.

Finally, note that when you do `cp -r dir1 dir2` when `dir2` already exists, then `dir1` will be copied inside `dir2`, rather than overwriting its content. That is, it will create `dir2/dir1`. If `dir1` doesn't contain hidden files, then you can write like this to overwrite the content of `dir2`:

```
cp -r dir1/* dir2/
```